# Error when trying to predict BERT model and obtaining classification report

Tags: python, multiclass-classification, multilabel-classification, bert, text-classification

I am following this [tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/multi-label-multi-class-text-classification-with-bert-transformer-and-keras-c6355eccb63a) about multi-label, multi-class classification using BERT. I am trying to get the predicted classification for `y_pred`, but when running it I got an error.

```
# Ready test data
test_y_kriteria = to_categorical(data_test['Kriteria'])
test_y_sentiment = to_categorical(data_test['Sentiment'])

test_x = tokenizer(
    text=data_test['Review Text'].to_list(),
    add_special_tokens=True,
    max_length=max_length,
    truncation=True,
    padding=True, 
    return_tensors='tf',
    return_token_type_ids = False,
    return_attention_mask = False,
    verbose = True)
# Run evaluation
model_eval = model.evaluate(
    x={'input_ids': test_x['input_ids']},
    y={'kriteria': test_y_kriteria, 'sentiment': test_y_sentiment}

#Predict
pred = model.predict(test_x)
```

The error is `ValueError: Unsupported value type BatchEncoding returned by IteratorSpec._serialize`. I tried changing `test_x` into a list

```
# Ready test data
test_y_kriteria = to_categorical(data_test['Kriteria'])
test_y_sentiment = to_categorical(data_test['Sentiment'])


tokenized_test_x = [
    tokenizer.tokenize(
    text=txt,
    add_special_tokens=True,
    max_length=max_length,
    truncation=True,
    padding=True, 
    return_tensors='tf',
    return_token_type_ids = False,
    return_attention_mask = False,
    verbose = True)
    for txt in data_test['Review Text'].to_list()]

# Run evaluation
model_eval = model.evaluate(
    x={'input_ids': test_x['input_ids']},
    y={'kriteria': test_y_kriteria, 'sentiment': test_y_sentiment}
)

#Predict
pred = model.predict(tokenized_test_x)
```

and I got this error instead `ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type list).`. I tried to look for solution for this, and most solutions suggested to use `asarray()`, so I ran `arr_token = np.asarray(tokenized_test_x, dtype=object)` and tried to predict using `arr_token` but it still returned the same error. How do I solve this?

Comment: Please post the code for the training data set, including the type.